# controller showing blank page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.2

I'm trying to create a new custom module.I have call one controller in another second controller. my problem is that i have call .phtml file in second controller my page is redirected but Blank page is showing.

First controller:

```
  class Spiffprogram_Spiff_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
  public function createNewPostAction() {
  $this->_redirect('spiffsuccess');//call another controller
  }
```

Second Controller:

```
  class SuccessSpiffProgram_SpiffSuccess_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
       {
          $block=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','core/template',
                                    array('template' => 'spiffsuccess/index.phtml')
                                   );
    }
   $this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
class SuccessSpiffProgram_SpiffSuccess_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {

      // Example URL to hit this action: mysite.com/so/index/index
public function indexAction()
{
    // Create a generic template block
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');

    // Assign your template to it
    // This path is relative to your current theme (eg: rwd/default/template/...)
    $block->setTemplate('spiffsuccess/index.phtml');

    // Render the template to the browser
    echo $block->toHtml();
}
    }
```

Comment: It's showing same problem...

Comment: @santosh edited my answer above, can you check now please?

Comment: @santosh be sure that your frontname is 'spiffsuccess'

Comment: thanks for help page content display but not showing the layout...only display the content without css...

Comment: You should do that using xml . Check tutorials for that http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/07/create-your-first-magento-module.html. Can you assign my answer as solved please?

Comment: no problem, take a look at this tutorials also:

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-update-layout-of-your-custom-controller-in-magento/

Why do you want to load template directly in your controller, instead of creating new layout and displaying the page design, using Magento layout?